# Evaluate the integral from $0$ to $\infty$

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

Consider the improper integral

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{x^4 +9}dx$$

So first I take the limit from b to $\infty$ to fix the integral

$$\lim_{b\to \infty} \int_0^b \frac{x}{x^4 +9}dx$$

now here is where I'm stuck, do I use trig sub to solve it or use a U-sub to get an arctan?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I tried that but then what can I do after I get $\lim_{b \to \infty}\frac{1}{2} \int_0^b \frac{du}{u^2 +9}$

Comment: I changed the substitution.

Comment: The integral $\;\int\frac{du}{u^2+9}\;$ is elementary and almost immediate.

Comment: What about trig sub _now_?

Comment: @YvesDaoust why $3x^2$?

Comment: because you'd get $x^4 = t^2/9$

Comment: @BrianMoehring: you are absolutely right, sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Substitute $$u=x^2$$ then we have $$du=2xdx$$

Comment: So I think I got it $\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{du}{u^2 +9}$ = $\frac{1}{6}(arctan(\frac{x}{3}))$ from $0$ to $b$. Then taking the limits gives me $\frac{\pi}{12}$

Comment: Yes thats ok so.

Comment: are you sure? i got something slightly different

Comment: I get this here $$\frac{1}{6} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{x^2}{3}\right)$$

Comment: i agree with this, but that's not what they have written in the comment. i dont want them getting confused when presumably writing this up.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that

$$x^4+9=(x^2+\sqrt6\,x+3)(x^2-\sqrt6\,x+3)$$

so now do partial fractions...

Comment: This is the "hard way".

Comment: @Yves Indeed so. But if he doesn't know how to solve the integral resulting from your hint let him work a little harder... :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$\frac{x\,dx}{x^4+9}=\frac32\frac19\frac{d(\frac{x^2}3)}{(\frac{x^2}3)^2+1}.$$